# Fastest way to output to file when using GNU parallel

Tags: linux, file-io, parallel-processing, qsub, gnu-parallel

I'm using parallel to process certain scripts in parallel which are really heavy. In `command1`...etc I am basically calling an R file.

**test1.sh:**

```
parallel ::: 'command1 > output1.txt' 'command2 > output2.txt' ...etc
```

**test2.sh:**

```
parallel ::: 'command7 > output7.txt' 'command8 > output8.txt' ...etc
```

.
.
.
**test10**

I am running `multiple-nodes.sh` using `qsub` where I'm executing the 10 files so that they run on different nodes (and cores) on the CPU  . It takes a couple of hours to complete. However, after the `multiple-nodes.sh` completes execution, I don't see it appearing in `qstat` but I still see the `R` script running (`command1`...etc) running when I check `top` processes in linux.

I thought this might be because linux (or is it parallel) writes to a file only after the execution of the script is complete. But this seems really slow because it's been 15 hours since the start of execution and the process has completed in qsub, but the commands are still running in top processes and the output files are being written slowly. The file sizes are increasing every few minutes.

I came across [Processing a big file using more cores](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Processing-a-big-file-using-more-cores) and **--files** tag of `GNU Parallel`.

So basically I have 2 questions:

1. Will [Processing a big file using more cores](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Processing-a-big-file-using-more-cores) from GNU Parallel be better than using `qsub` for running processes in different nodes (and cores) on the cpu?
2. Will `--files` be a better (and faster) option than `>` operator in linux to write into output files?

It would be really helpful if there's any supporting code provided. Even if it is just an answer to one of the questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer 2: It will be the same speed. The benefit with --files/--results is that you do not have to make up filenames.

Comment: Could you please back up with some reason? I mean, what does `--files` use? How is it actually working or why would it take the same time?

Comment: --files and --results open a redirection file for stderr and stdout. It is for all practical purposes the same as redirecting the output using > and 2>. Technically it uses the Perl open3 call to do this.